# импорт данных из XML-файла в SQL Manager Lite for PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, postgresql, импорт

у меня есть файлы, которые хотел бы импортировать в БД
Есть таблица `Test` с полем `xml`
пытаюсь сделать импорт

```
COPY
  public."Test"
( 
  "TestXML" 
)
FROM 'D:\file.xml';
```

Вылетает ошибка `ERROR:  could not open file "/file.xml" for reading: No such file or directory`

Понимаю, что скорее всего проблема в неправильности пути, перепробовал разные вариации, ошибка та же. Не могу понять в чем ошибаюсь

---

Решение было в экранировании слэшов в пути к файлу.

```
COPY    
public."Test"
    (
      "TestXML"
    )
    FROM E'D:\\file.xml';
```

Файл читает, но теперь проблема в другом, при считывании файла вылетает ошибка

```
ОШИБКА:  invalid XML content
CONTEXT:  COPY Test, строка 1, колонка TestXML: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"
```

Думаю проблема в переносе строки, в скрипте дописываю `DELIMITER '\n'` и вылетает ошибка

```
ОШИБКА:  разделитель для COPY должен быть однобайтным символом
```

Также пробовал `WITH DELIMITER AS E'\n'` и все также вылетает ошибка

```
ОШИБКА:  разделителем для COPY не может быть символ новой строки или возврата каретки
```

В документации пишется, что команда COPY FROM распознаёт следующие спецпоследовательности: \n, \r и тп. Тоесть принимать разделитель оно должно.
Подскажите, в чем тут ошибка.

Comment: файл-то где лежит?

Comment: @Мелкий в корне диска Д, пробовал также указывать обычный локальный путь к файлу

Comment: винда чтоль? Ну вы хоть указывайте в вопросе что под какой-то экзотикой запускаете. А о показываете абсолютный путь в стиле unix. Попробуйте корректно экранированный абсолютный путь до файлы, который понимает ваша ОС. Ну и убедитесь что файл лежит на той же системе что и postgresql его пытается читать.

Comment: @Мелкий да винда, вообще postgresql лежит на сервере, на сервере есть локальный диск D, в корне которого лежит файл, также пробовал указывать `'D:\file.xml'`